# How do ants get oxygen in deep colonies?

Tags: entomology, respiration, ant

With ant colonies getting to be +7 feet deep, how does oxygen renew that deep for their respiration demand?

Comment: A basic Google search returns several relevant papers, which could be a start:   [*nest aeration ant colony oxygen*](https://www.google.se/search?client=ms-android-sonymobile&ei=gJHUWuTBLcyjsAGL2JqQBQ&q=nest+aeration+ant+colony+oxygen&oq=nest+aeration+ant+colony+oxygen&gs_l)

Comment: Thank you. Obviously I tried searching google first. The connotation of your use of "basic" is belittling.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't my intention. My point was that it was a quick search without much effort or thought on my part, that still looked useful. I didn't have time for anything else right now (or an answer), but thought that it could still be useful to get an overview, or to rephrase the question based on a bit more background. Also, if you tried searching google before asking, it is useful if you add some of what you found, and what information you are missing/found lacking.

Comment: We do expect questions to show some effort to research answer prior to posting (homework rule). so if you include some prior research you will be fine. google provides a few useful sources but not a lot. Ant have multiple strategies and it is a hotbed of research right now. keep in mind the true extent of some ant colonies was only recently discovered.